# how to do a insert statement in web service asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

i am suppose to receive the data from android to my web service and my web service is going to insert the data into my data base. how am i going to do about it to insert the data from my web service to database.

this is my start of code :

```
 [WebMethod]
    public StudentTransactions GetStudentTransactions(string Name, string CLass, string NRIC, int StallNo, float AmountSpent)
     {
        SqlCommand sql1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT Into StudentTransactions (Name, CLass,NRIC,StallNo,AmountSpent) VALUES (Name,CLass,NRIC,StallNo,AmountSpent)");
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ncpsdbbConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
         {
             conn.Open();

             {

             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ncpsdbbConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Into StudentTransactions (Name, CLass,NRIC,StallNo,AmountSpent) VALUES (@Name,@CLass,@NRIC,@StallNo,@AmountSpent)");
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Add the values and params like so:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName", [Some Value]);
```

Try the above.
Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: do i need to add this statement in ? example : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", userInfo.Country);

Comment: Yeah, you have to define the params w/values for each insert param

Comment: i deifine after the command.ExecuteNonQuery? what is the some value?

Comment: Define if before you call ExecuteNonQuery. "Some Value" refers to the content of the parms you're inserting ex:@name

Comment: i got error: my "GetStudentTransactions" tell me not all code path return a value.

Comment: The problem is that your method is expected to return a StudentTransaction. It's a bit misleading that your function is called GetStudentTransactions when it's in fact adding them. You have to either create a StudentTransaction and return it, or change your method signature to return void

Comment: i change it to this instead : public static void InsertStudentTransactions?

Comment: Sure, give that a try. I would perhaps use singular form InsertStudentTransaction since it's a single record

Comment: okays! thanks i will try run on my andriod and see if it workds on my server with this code u provided me. thanks alot. one and one more question. after inserting i would like to do a update where shall i put my update statement at?